# Correct way of using session in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, mod-wsgi

I started with sqlalchey and everything is good. But my question is: How to use session on a correct way.

For example:
I have a file like (sqlsetts.py):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql://root@127.0.0.1/test')
engine.execute("SET NAMES 'utf8'")

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=True, autocommit=True, expire_on_commit=True)

session = Session()
```

Every time I need to use a session i use following:

```
class test:

   from sqlsettings import session
   def testfunc(self):
       self.session.query... bla bla
```

Is that correct way to include session from a file or to make a new one for each function?

Comment: As you probably know SQLAlchemy has pretty extensive docs about using sessions (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html). There some definitive "don'ts" but other than that everything depend on your application.

Comment: I read, but I don't lnow again when to use sessions...

Comment: that doc includes a specific section called [When do I construct a Session, when do I commit it, and when do I close it?](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it) - I've been trying to answer this question for people for years, that answer is *still* not good enough?

Comment: For me, that one was enoguh. Thanks! Documentation was big, so i couldn't find what I wanted. Once more, thanks